# Crystal Reports: Use Sub-Report parameter values in Main-Report

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, report

I have a Sub-Report that takes 2 date parameters (Start and End date) 
A Main-Report that has Sub-report nested in it. When I refresh the report, I get a prompt to enter the dates. 
All I'm trying to do is display those dates in (start date - end date) format on Main-Report.

Here's what I tried.

Created a formula (SharedStartDate) in Sub-Report as

```
Shared StringVar startDate :=  ToText({?@start_DT},"MM/dd/yyyy");
startDate;
```

Created another formula in Main-Report with the same name (SharedStartDate)

```
Shared StringVar startDate;
startDate
```

When I use this formula in the main-report, I get empty text.

I'm not sure what Am i doing wrong, I'm pretty new working with CR
Thank you guys in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: where did you place the formula in main report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care of few things while passing the value to main report.

1. Formula need to be placed on the sub report before passing the value.
2. When value is used in main report then the resulting formula should be kept in coming sections in the design.. not in the preceeding sections then you won't get the value.
3. one more option would be (`not suggested`)since you are manuplating parameters then link the parameters from mainreport to subreport and use that parameter at any section irrespective of sub report location in report.

Comment: 1 : Formula is placed on the Sub-Report and it shows the values I pass as parameters.

Comment: Formula is placed on SubReport & it shows the values I pass as parameters, It is Suppressed  <br/>
Not sure if I understandwhere exactly should the formula be placed on MainReport<br/>
This is the structure of my Main-Report<br/>
**Report Header** - Blank<br/>
**Page Header**   - <br/>
                    Report Title<br/>
                    Report Date<br/>
                    Report Criteria<br/>
**Details**       - Sub-Report<br/>
**Report Footer** - Blank<br/>
**Page Footer**   - Blank<br/>
Report criteria in **Page Header** is where I'm trying to display those values from Sub-Report<br/>

Comment: since your sub report is in detail and you are trying to display in page header of main report.. value will be blank. one workaround would be since you have date parameter in sub report create the same parameter in main report aswell and link both using sub report links... now use parameter to display in page header of main report.

Comment: That worked !  @Siva
Here's what I did. I deleted DateRange parameter from MainReport, Refreshed the Datasource location on the subreport (by literally just repeating the process). Created the DateRange parameter again in MainReport and also 2 Formulas to get start and end date

Comment: ...Continued...  

In the preview window, on main-report, right clicked on sub-report and "Change Subreport links", 
Linked the Mainreport fields (the 2 formulas I created) End_Date & Start_Date (by moving them from "Available fields" to "Fields to link to") to Subreport parameters end_DT & start_DT respectively and Unchecked "Select data in subreport based on field"

     

  
Thanks a lot for your suggestions !

Comment: I am glad that you are able to solve your issue... you are welcome :)